# Closing a (remote) linux command-line interface

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh

If I run code (e.g. an executable) on a Linux command-line interface and then close the interface, what happens? Does the executable keep running in the background? What if it requires user-input? Can I "return to it" (e.g. to supply it with user input) during a later session?

Does this behavior change if the command-line interface is accessed remotely (e.g. via SSH)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you ran said command in a program like `screen` or `tmux`; or you have backgrounded (`bg`) and disowned (`disown`) said program, it will be killed when it's parent shell dies (and closing a terminal emulator's window will kill the shell)

Answer (score 1):

Variations of this question have been asked before. You can find them if you search on `nohup`, `screen` or `tmux`.

But briefly:
When you close the connection of the network interface goes offline the program you are running gets told that you disconnected (with a SIGHUP) and terminates.

If you want them to keep running despite this you need to tell them to ignore this hangup signal, which you can do by prepending the nohup command.

A much more comfortable method is to run `screen` or `tmux` which will keep your state is it was until you reconnect. (And which can do much much more).